# Upload recent downloaded file using Selenium webdriver- PYTHON

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I want to upload a file using Selenium whose name I don't know, the only thing I know is that it's in the downloads folder and it's the recent file. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with selenium. You can use native libraries from python to obtain desired result.

```
import os
import glob

# * matches all files in directory
# if you need other specific file types
# use *.[type], for example *.py
files_in_dir = glob.glob('[path to your folder]/*') 
recent_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
```

`os.path.getctime` refers to last metadata change time in current path in system. This way you can filter out and get most recent file with recent date.
`glob` module is used to find specific file patterns in specified directory. Read more about `glob` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html).
`os` module provides some utility capabilites from operating system. More about `os` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).